# a rather strange phenomenon Excel MFC ADO database programming

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, windows, visual-studio-2010

Now I'm dealing with Excel with MFC Ado Database programming. I have successfully connected to the Excel.

But I found that when I connect to a existing Excel file, the Excel file contains header names. But that, the content in the Excel are typed into, not inserting to by using Ado SQL.
The result is I get the error message: could not find the specified object. I'm sure the specified sheet name is spelled correctly.

When I use the Ado SQL to insert the data, then I can execute the SAME SQL successfully.
In fact, the data inseted into Excel with ADO SQL is completely same with I typed before.

The typed data cannot be queried with ADO SQL? I wonder I have missed something important?

I have no idea why this happened.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problems.

In fact, I did make a mistake in spelling the sheet name, sheet name should append a symbol '$'. It's just the '$' symbol stuck me.

For example, if the display sheet name is 'Demo', then the sheet name in the SQL should be 'Demo$'.

The final correct SQL is *

```
Select * from [Demo$]
```